# What are the common methods for having external companies testing your software?

Tags: testing

We are a couple of entrepenours who have developed a cross-browser app and a backend administration system for the app. Or actually, we paid a company to develop it. Now we want it tested profesionally, but we dont want to use the same company for this purpose.

The tests may involve

1. Integration Testing
2. Functional Testing
3. System Testing
4. Stress Testing
5. Performance Testing
6. Usability Testing

For some of the tests, we think that the actual source code is required. We dont feel komfortable giving our source code away "just like that", to unknown parties, so what are the common methods for having external companies testing ones software?

Comment: sqa.stackexchange.com or programmers.stackexchange.com might be better suited to your question, I'm not sure if it fits in stackoverflow.  - In my experience, at least the first three are usually done inhouse at the developer's company. A specialized (professional) QA company will have some kind of legal binding non disclosure agreements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't really need to give the source to perform the mentioned tests. you need to provide working environments or provide binaries and instructions how to deploy them. it seems sufficient for 1,2 (i don't know what does 3 means), 4 and 5. It's way too late for usability testing. it should have been done during UI design phase (how do you want to test it right now?)

but those tests are not sufficient. you forgot about penetration testing. and above tests are black box testing and they can show you how the application works.

but if you have any real plans for this application you must be sure it's maintainable. and for this you need the whitebox testing, you have to analyze the code.

you can start with automated analyzing to check the overall quality of the code. but at the end you will still need good programmers to perform the code review. but you don't really have to give them the code. you can invite them to your office and let them review the code on your workstations. unless your idea is so simple and brilliant that only one look at the code is enough to reproduce it. in such case you will need to sign NDA or give some shares to the expert who will take care of the quality